# media queries not loading

Tags: html, css, media-queries

This has been killing me for the past few hours..

No media queries appear to be making any changes in my code. Nothing shows up in chrome dev tools, yet its in my stylesheet.

I'm just trying to set a `max-width` on the `body`, and `left` and `right` margins to auto when the size is above `768px`.

Here's my post `css` code:

```
body {
  bottom: 0;

  @media and screen (width >= 768px) {
    max-width: 80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }

}
```

which ouputs this css:

```
body {
  bottom: 0;

}

@media and screen (min-width: 768px) {

  body {
    max-width: 80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
}
```

I included `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` in my head tag. Is there something I'm missing?

It works fine when its not inside the media query.

http://jsfiddle.net/2msm1p1L/

Comment: post a jsfiddle with your markup

Comment: Better yet, do it here on SO in a "snippet"

Comment: Think you've switched `screen` and `and`...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2msm1p1L/

Comment: @Shikkediel It appears I have, but doesn't seem to fix it.

Comment: nvrmd, totally works I was derping. @Shikkediel if you submit that as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Appreciate it but I think allicam would deserve it, she was only a tiny bit later than me with a full answer. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got your order mixed up - `and` comes after `screen`

```css
body {
  bottom: 0;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  body {
    max-width: 80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
}
.placeholder {
  background: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="placeholder"></div>
```